# How do you make the same command but it will change according to the day

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that will give you a schedule depending on the day of the week, here's my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'itmawdschedule01',
    description: "This will help you  with your schedule",
    execute(message, args){
        var weekday = new Array(7);

        weekday[0] = message.channel.send(`message`);
        weekday[1] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[2] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[3] = "Thursday";
        weekday[4] = "Friday";
        weekday[5] = "Saturday";
        weekday[6] = "Sunday";
    }
}
```

but it gave me an error on

```js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

I have no idea how to fix this and as of now I'm all out of ideas. Thanks <3

Comment: Could you explain what your code is trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a different outcome depending on the day of the week, you should use a [`switch`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement and the [`Date.prototype.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function.

```js
const today = new Date().getDay(); // returns a number from 0 to 6 (0=Sunday 1=Monday 2=Tuesday ...)

switch (today) {
  case 0:
    console.log('Today is Sunday');
    // code...
    break;
  case 1:
    console.log('Today is Monday');
    // code...
    break;
  case 2:
    console.log('Today is Tuesday');
    // code...
    break;
  case 3:
    console.log('Today is Wednesday');
    // code...
    break;
  case 4:
    console.log('Today is Thursday');
    // code...
    break;
  case 5:
    console.log('Today is Friday');
    // code...
    break;
  case 6:
    console.log('Today is Saturday');
    // code...
    break;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in curly brackets goes map entry or function body.

```
weekday[0] = () => { message.channel.send(`message`) };
```

Probably you mean the second variant.